# template for a function

Tags: c++, templates

This question was asked to me in an interview:

Lets say you have a function which can take any kind of arguments and any number of arguments.
How would you write a template function for the same?

I do not know the exact answer. could anybody suggest?

Comment: actually sorry to be a pedant, but you said "I do not know the exact answer. "

Comment: Aren't interview questions about variadic templates a bit premature ? I mean, C++0x is not officially here (MSVC doesn't support variadic templates yet), and any standard compliant solution involves writing a truckload of macros, which I wouldn't like an employee to do in real world code.

Comment: Not knowing the exact answer doesn't necessarily mean to know an inexact answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They checked your awareness of the upcoming C++ standard. The new feature is called "Variadic templates" and looks like this:

```
template<typename... Args> void f( const Args&... args )
{
    // do something
}
```

For a more complicated examples see, e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/41533).

Comment: Doesn't that mean that all the arguments will be of the same type?

Comment: The argument list could also be `Args&&...` for perfect forwarding.

Comment: reading the [the High-Integrity C++ Manual](http://www.codingstandard.com/) it states that *High Integrity CPP Rule 11.* - *Use of the ellipsis notation (...) to indicate an unspecified number of arguments should be avoided*. Has this changed for C++0x?

Comment: @Default: The ellipsis and variadic templates are completely different things, even if they are spelled the same (ellipsis: `void foo( int x, ... );`, variadic template: `template <typename... Args> void foo( Args&&... x );`). C++0x still has ellipsis, and it is still not recommended to use it for different reasons that include the fact that it is not type safe and it does not handle user defined classes.

Comment: @David: thanks for the explanation. It looks the same for me though :) I guess that the type safety and user defined classes have been improved with the variadic templates then

Comment: @Philipp: It could, but then this example would demonstrate two completely different things. I think it's bad from pedagogical point of view.

Comment: @Default: in the ellipsis notation (not a template feature) the number and types of the arguments are unknown and *removed* from the call, agreement on the number and type of the arguments has to be handled elsewhere (first argument to printf) and cannot be verified by the compiler. All objects must be POD. In the variadic template case, because it is instantiated at the place of call, the compiler passes the types (and implicitly number) of arguments to the template, making it type safe. See this simple example: http://www.ideone.com/dfM59, no format string has been passed, types are known.

Answer (score 4):

In C++03, for any number of argument in function template is not possible. However, for any type of argument you can write:

```
template<typename T, typename U> 
void f( const T & t, const U &u )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: i am aware of this and this does not answer my question

Answer (score 2):

I agree that they were most probably looking for *variadic templates*, but for the sake of it, different approaches that can be taken in C++03:

Using a variant type

Use a container of a variant type. In this case `boost::variant` will not work, as it limits the number of types, but you can use `boost::any`:

```
void foo( std::vector< boost::any > args );
```

Compared to variadic templates, user code will be much more cumbersome, as instead of writting `foo( a, b, c, d )`, they will have to manually create the vector upfront. The syntax could be simplified by means of variadic macros (if the compiler supports them) and or helper templated functions to adapt the syntax, but this can quite easily become a mess.

The C way (non-template):

Use the ellipsis notation to write a function that takes an unknown number of arguments (and types):

```
void foo( type x, ... )
```

This approach has many shortcommings. The first one is that it is not typesafe, the compiler will not be able to detect that the arguments are the correct number or types, and it is undefined behavior if any of the arguments is a non-POD type, which limits usability from *any* type to POD types, which might or not be a limiting factor (you can always pass in a pointer to your non-POD object). Overall this is more complex to handle, and much more error prone so it should be avoided.

Not answering the question at all

In very few situations a single function should be able to take an unknown number of arguments of unknown types. Logging and i/o can require this, `printf` being such example. But that can be handled in C++ by means of operator overloading (in particular `operator<<`) and chaining. In a comment `bind` has been suggested, so yes, perfect forwarding in generic code is one such case, `bind`, `std::thread`...

It think this to be a good answer for an interview, as you can then discuss what the actual need for the function is, and whether there is any better alternative. It can be argued that if at the end you do need a container of a variant type, you can abuse operator overloading to simplify the syntax. Examples of this would be the `boost::assign` library, and in those lines you can create a helper argument builder as in:

```
class args {
public:
   args() {}
   operator std::vector<boost::any>&() {
      return v;
   }
   template <typename T>
   args& operator,( T x ) {
      boost::any a = x;
      v.push_back( a );
      return *this;
   }
private:
   std::vector<boost::any> v;
};
// usage:
void foo( std::vector<boost::any> a ) {
   std::cout << "Received " << a.size() << " arguments" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
   foo(( args(), 1, 5.0, "a string", std::vector<int>(5,10) ));
}
```

Variadic templates

And of course, the best option that is a c++0x compiler that handles variadic templates, that requires no extra boiler plate code, and will make it much simpler to write both user code (directly as a regular function call) and the implementation of the function, whatever it is. As a motivating example, building a `vector<boost::any>` with variadic args:

```
typedef std::vector<boost::any> anyvector_t

// Stop condition, adding nothing at the end
void build_vector_impl( anyvector_t& ) {}

// Intermediate step, add a new argument to the vector and recurse:
template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void build_vector_impl( anyvector_t& v, Head head, Tail... tail ) {
   v.push_back( boost::any(head) );
   build_vector_impl( v, tail... );
}

// Syntactic sugar: make it return the vector:
template <typename... Args>
anyvector_t build_vector( Args... args ) {
   anyvector_t res;
   build_vector_impl( res, args... );
   return res;
}
// Test:
int main() {
   std::cout << "Number of args: " 
             << build_vector( 1, 5, "Hi", std::vector<int>( 5, 10 ) ).size() 
             << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio does indeed support variadic macros.

Comment: @DeadMG: corrected, when I worked with VS we had to support VS2003/05/08, and variadic macros were forbidden, probably due to 2003 restrictions, as they seem to be available in 2005. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: "I am still to find a single situation where a single function..."  std::bind()?

Comment: @ybungalobill: Right, generic perfect forwarding. How many times have you needed to implement anything similar? `boost::bind` was implemented before I even thought of using *generic callable* objects :) I am editing to soften the statement.

Comment: well, one place where we will use it frequently is in constructor inheritance. The committee removed them because it seems redundant when you can do the same thing with a generic variadic constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That is not about templates. It's about variable arguments.

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Comment: If the question asks about "a template function", then it's certainly about templates.